# Looking for a story about a teacher who meets a ghost

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, ghost

Can anyone help me locate this book:

It is about a woman, maybe a school teacher, who one night, as she was staying late in the school after hours, encounters a ghost from a couple hundred years ago. I believe the ghost was a woman looking for her daughter.

Comment: Hi Keena. I have edited your post to remove the second question. Hopefully now it can be reopened. The second question didn't seem to be science fiction or fantasy anyway.